# Can't get PHP handle its session with memcached and unix sockets

Tags: php, session, configuration, memcached

Server OS: **Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS**

PHP: **5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15**

Memcached: **1.4.22** (self compiled)

Memcached running as service with this configuration: **/usr/local/bin/memcached -v -m 512 -u memcache -s /tmp/memcached.sock -a 666**

```
echo "stats" | nc -U /tmp/memcached.sock
```

works fine. All I need to do is to edit the **/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini** and change the values of **session.save_handler** and **session.save_path** but my save_path never seems to be correct. I always just see *Failed to write session data*. My tries so far:

```
session.save_path = "/tmp/memcached.sock"
session.save_path = "/tmp/memcached.sock:0"
session.save_path = "unix:/tmp/memcached.sock"
session.save_path = "unix:///tmp/memcached.sock"
session.save_path = "unix:///tmp/memcached.sock:0"
```

None of them worked so I ask if someone can enlighten me. :)

Thanks in advance!

Tekin

Answer (score 0):

When storing sessions in memcached, I've only ever done this by installing a php memcached extension installed, and by setting the storage to memcached.

The extension
http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached

Configuring sessions to be stored there
http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php

I usually go with:

```
  php_value session.save_handler memcached
  php_value session.save_path "127.0.0.1:11211"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That is the way I also normally use it but our servers gets problems with exhausted ports because the connection to our MySQL server and to Memcached leave about 20.000 TIME_WAIT ports each so I want to get rid of half of them by using Memcached via Unix sockets.